# Django admin - using autocomplete and filter on choices fields (not ManyToMany or ForeignKey)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-filters, django-admin-filters

This is my model:

```
class Academic(models.Model):

SCHOOL_COLLEGE_SERVICE = [
    ('School Of Humanities', 'School Of Humanities'),
    ('School Of Culture & Creative Arts', 'School Of Culture & Creative Arts'),
    ('School Of Modern Languages & Cultures', 'School Of Modern Languages & Cultures'),
    ('School Of Critical Studies', 'School Of Critical Studies'),
    ('Arts  College Of Arts Administration', 'Arts  College Of Arts Administration'),
    ]

school = models.CharField(choices=SCHOOL_COLLEGE_SERVICE, max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

I'd like to have a nice autocomplete / filter in my Django administration interface. Unfortunately it seems that it is not possible to have autocomplete if the dataset doesn't come from a ManyToMany or ForeignKey relationship. This is what I tried:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Academic, Partner, Project
from admin_auto_filters.filters import AutocompleteFilter
import django_filters

@admin.register(Academic)
class AcademicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['surname', 'forename']
    #school = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=Academic.SCHOOL_COLLEGE_SERVICE)
    #autocomplete_fields = ['school']
```

I know I can also set a queryset like so:

```
class SchoolFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Academic
        fields = ['school',]
```

But Django still complains that `The value of 'autocomplete_fields[0]' must be a foreign key or a many-to-many field.` How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Do you have more than 5 schools in your actual model/data?

Comment: This is one of the choices. In this specific case I only have 5, in other models I have even 20 or 30 choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a form **choicefield** as a autocomplete dropdown easily using **django-autocomplete-light** package. This package also supports queryset.

In forms.py,

```
class AcademicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    SCHOOL_COLLEGE_SERVICE = [
    ('School Of Humanities', 'School Of Humanities'),
    ('School Of Culture & Creative Arts', 'School Of Culture & Creative Arts'),
    ('School Of Modern Languages & Cultures', 'School Of Modern Languages & Cultures'),
    ('School Of Critical Studies', 'School Of Critical Studies'),
    ('Arts  College Of Arts Administration', 'Arts  College Of Arts Administration'),
    ]
    school = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SCHOOL_COLLEGE_SERVICE,
                               widget=autocomplete.ListSelect2(url='school_autocomplete'))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Academic
        fields = ['school', 'other_your_model_fields']
```

In urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('school-autocomplete', SchoolAutocompleteView.as_view(), name='school_autocomplete'),
    ]
```

In views.py,

```
from dal import autocomplete

class SchoolAutocompleteView(autocomplete.Select2ListView):

    def get_list(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return []

        SCHOOL_COLLEGE_SERVICE = ['School Of Humanities',
                                  'School Of Culture & Creative Arts',
                                  'School Of Modern Languages & Cultures',
                                  'School Of Critical Studies',
                                  'Arts  College Of Arts Administration']

        return SCHOOL_COLLEGE_SERVICE
```

Now you use modelform in your admin class,

```
@admin.register(Academic)
class AcademicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AcademicForm
    ....
    ....
```

for more details, doc_link- https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that I need to triplicate my CHOICES, i.e. they need to be in my models.py, in forms.py, and also in views.py ?

Comment: @HBMCS you don't need to set choices in models.py, also you can set empty choices i.e [] in forms.py. You define choice list in only views.py. I just copy paste your choices for better understanding.

Comment: @HBMCS I edited my answer. **remove choices from forms**

Comment: ~~Right, I do have my choices if I point my browser on that school-autocomplete url. Nevertheless, in the Admin interface the choices field is empty.~~ - Apologies, I didn't collect my static files and wasn't loading the JavaScript files. Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: I celebrated too early. When I hit 'save' Django complains that the selection is not valid. For instance: "Select a valid choice. Crit - English Language & Linguistics is not one of the available choices."

Comment: then you must give **choices=<your_choice_list>** instead of empty choices in **school** form field. Since django validate **selected choice** belongs or not you_choice_list.

Comment: @HBMCS I update the answer. Added **SCHOOL_COLLEGE_SERVICE** choices for **school form field**.

Comment: I appreciate the effort; this is a duplication which goes against the DRY concept. It does work though now, I give you that. I tseems to me that the best solution is almost always to have a separate model with a foreign/manytomany key. I'll accept your answer anyway because it does work in the end, although I'm going to use a separate model in the end.