# Search/Filter Dropdown in Django Admin Panel for standard CharField

Tags: django-models, drop-down-menu, django-admin, admin

I am using Django to build data models including a model *Company*. Some of the fields belonging to this model are limited to set choices using the choices='' argument. Some of these fields have a large number of choices, for example a country CharField which lists all countries. Finding the right value among the long list can be tedious so I want to be able to search across the given choice values. This is easy to do for ForeignKey/ManytoMany fields using autocomplete_fields = [] as seen in the attached screenshot (from a different model) but can't seem to find a method for implementing this with a normal CharField with lots of choices. This seems like something that should be built into the Django for the admin panel but I can't find anything within the docs. Please how can I implement a search/filter dropdown for any given *(non FK/m2m)* fields? Thanks in advance. If there's anymore information I can provide let me know and I will.

[image: Example of functionality I want for a normal CharField]

```
country = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, null=True)
```

Model code added. This COUNTRY_CHOICES array is what I would like to be able to select from in a searchable dropdown list.

Comment: please share model code

Comment: I answered similar question. This answer may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69647827/django-admin-using-autocomplete-and-filter-on-choices-fields-not-manytomany-o/69648463#69648463